# Move read more link down with the text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The read more link does not go down with the text itself when the remaining text is shown.

I tried `position: relative;` on the "read more" link which is `<a href="#">Read More</a>` but no luck, because the `<a href="#">Read More</a>` is not a child of `<div="main">` but it is a child of `<div id="sidebox">` and it is in a separate javascript file too.

How can I make the "read more" link move down with the text?

**The HTML File:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <style>
            #mainwrapper #sidebox {top:100px;right:2%;width:18%;position:absolute;direction:rtl;}
            #mainwrapper #sidebox #main {top:80px;position:absolute;right:0%;left:0%;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;}
            #mainwrapper #sidebox #title {font-weight:bold;font-size: 25px;color: rgba(74, 74, 74, 1.0);text-align: center;}
            #mainwrapper #sidebox #sub {line-height: 30px;font-size: 16px;color: rgba(74, 74, 74, 1.0);text-align: justify;}
            #mainwrapper #sidebox a {text-decoration:none;color:grey;font-size:20px;position:relative;top:300px;}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="mainwrapper">
            <div id="sidebox">
                <div id="main">
                    <p id="title">SOME TITLE</p>
                    <p id="sub">SOME LONG TEXT</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="readmore.js"></script>
<script>$('#main').readmore({speed: 500});</script>
```

**Part of the code in the readmore.js:**

```
 var readmore = 'readmore',
  defaults = {
    speed: 100,
    collapsedHeight: 200,
    heightMargin: 16,
    moreLink: '<a href="#">Read More</a>',
    lessLink: '<a href="#">Close</a>',
    embedCSS: true,
    blockCSS: 'display: block; width: 100%;',
    startOpen: false,
    // callbacks
    blockProcessed: function() {},
    beforeToggle: function() {},
    afterToggle: function() {}
  },
```

Comment: can you add jsfiddle for same please

Comment: As long as the 'read more' link appears after the text and you haven't fixed it anythin in place (not used position:absolute), it should move down.   You could try adding a `<div style='clear:both'></div>` just above the more link.

Comment: @PravinWaychal,Don't No why, but doesnt work in jsfiddle, it does on my system

Comment: @freedomn-m, tried what you said, and no luck still. To remind you, the link is in the js file not in the html

Comment: that makes no sense - it will be added to the html by js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the positioning of #main causes some problems, change your css to this:

```
    #mainwrapper #sidebox {width:15%;direction:rtl;position:absolute;top:100px;right:2%;}
    #mainwrapper #sidebox #title {font-weight:bold;font-size: 25px;color: rgba(74, 74, 74, 1.0);text-align: center;}
    #mainwrapper #sidebox #sub {line-height: 30px;font-size: 16px;color: rgba(74, 74, 74, 1.0);text-align: justify;}
    a {text-decoration:none;color:navy;font-size:20px;}
```

Answer (score 0):

This maybe due to you have not added CSS try below and check jsfiddle link as well

```
#main{
  max-height: 80px; /*change as per your context*/
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Ls07kkqu/)